# Is there a way to log the body of the http request in Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I need to log the http body of the requests in Azure AppService.

I notice there's this app service logs. 
Is there a configuration here to that i can make that logs the body in the Azure Storage.

[image]

What's the best way to do log the body in Azure Storage (without writing the code myself)? :)

Comment: I do not think there is a way to automatically store the body in azure storage. Best thing would be to add the body as a custom dimension in application insight

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Vihanga Bandara said, there is no way to store the body in storage, you need to custom the event by using [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview).

For app service logs, we can only get the log information like this

```
2020-05-28 07:29:58 TONYTESTNETCORE POST /api/TodoItems X-ARR-LOG-ID=5a94c854-d4ff-4b2d-b2c4-6fdebb457cee 443 - 167.220.233.180 PostmanRuntime/7.24.1 ARRAffinity=152c130e21c95ce31be52418aed58ed4a1114b560e108246b2120e2d4dbf27ee - tonytestnetcore.azurewebsites.net 201 0 0 443 1359 62
```

Reference:

[Application Insights API for custom events and metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#trackevent)

[TrackRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#trackrequest)